# Is it possible to pass react context to a js class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a requirement where I have to perform some complex operations and besed on that result have to some api calls etc. After that api call I have to transform the result and save in context passed from react component.

```js
class User extends React.PureComponent {
  static contextType = UserContext;

  user = new UserHelper(this.context);

  someAction() {
    this.user(); 
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.someAction}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: By context are you referring to the react specific context API

Comment: Yes, I am planning to pass the react context to this helper class so that I can call different updaters defined in that context based on some logic there